# Freeing the memory of structure in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have  a  following sturcture for creating linked list, how can I free the allocated memeory?

```
typedef struct linked_list {
    struct linkedl_ist *number;
    POINTER           house;
} list;


typedef  list  *LIST;  
typedef void pointer
```

i have following list

```
LIST l1;
l1 = some_function(pointer);
```

These `l1` is constructed using some variables. This is a linked list data structure as i mentioned. How can I free the memory allocated for `l1`?

[EDIT]

`l1` holds a memory of 8 byte.

Comment: It depends on how it is allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l1` doesn't need to be freed. It's on the stack. Return from the function you're in and it will automatically go away. The way to free what `l1` points to is the same as the way to free the rest of the elements of the list: walk the list (using `->number`) and free each element as you go.

```
LIST node = l1;
LIST next;
while (node != NULL)
{
    next = node->number;
    free(node);
    node = next;
}
```

Comment: Note that `l1` is a a `list *`.  So while the pointer variable itself doesn't need to be freed, you need to free the `list` it's pointing to.

Comment: @Matthew: Whoops, missed the * in the typedef. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to free the memory pointers individually. There's not really a magic bullet here, you have to loop over the linked list and free the pointers for each node, then if your linked list itself is dynamically allocated, you have to free that.

It's important to free things in the correct order so you don't end up with [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). In other words, if you have pointer p which points to another pointer p2, you need to be sure to free p2 and then p. You don't want to free p before you free p2, because when you try to free p2 you are going through a dangling pointer to do it (e.g. free(p->p2) but p is already freed).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should free each element of your list manually, starting from l1, then l1->number etc.

Comment: If you do it this way, you'll have to be very, very careful. If you free `l1`, and then try to access `l1->number`, you're touching memory you've already freed. Which is a big no-no. If you want to do it this way, you need to make sure you pull all the data you need into locals before you actually free the element.

Comment: That's right. Actually I'm working on these list too, but I have still much work to do (as you can see) :)

Comment: I don't have much experience on these things. Can you please give me some useful links that you refer for it or probably some examples realted to it.

Comment: try here: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html for an example, or 
http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/ for a manual.